# Laravel root route "/" doesn't work inside prefixed routes on subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have the project with the following routes:

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:admin'], function () {
    // this is working on my local machine but it's skipped on server which is a subdomain.
        Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('admin.dashboard'); 

        // other routes here. all of them working fine
        Route::resource('pages', 'PageController')->except(['show']);
    });
});
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index'); // this is working fine
```

On my local machine when I open app.test/admin everything work as expected. I can see my login page if I'm not logged in or the dashboard view if I am.
On the server, which is a subdomain, if I open subdomain.app.com/admin I see nothing. The server response is 200 without any error. All subsequent routes like admin/pages work fine.

The document root in apache is set to the root of the project, not inside public folder. I use the following .htaccess file in the root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```

I expect the /admin route to show the dashboard view but I get a blank page. Where can be the issues when there is no error?

Comment: Did you also test locally with a subdomain?

Comment: Well, I did not. I use valet for my local dev machine with nginx and on the server is apache. But I will try to make a subdomain and test it locally.

Comment: I created a subdomain on my local machine and everything is working fine. /admin routes is opening.

Comment: Is there a reason you're rewriting to `server.php` and not `index.php` ?

Comment: Yes. .htaccess file is in the root of the project, not inside public folder. Server document root was configured to be in the root of the project /var/www/html and not inside public folder /var/www/html/public. Thats why I use htaccess to rewrite server.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer ;)

The problem was that I had a folder called admin in my public folder wich was the same as the route I was trying to access. Renaming that folder to a random name fixed my /admin route.

Answer (score 0):

Does building your Routes list like this help at all?

```php
    Route::group(
        [
            'domain' => '{account}.app.test',
            'prefix' => 'admin', // This is the URL prefix
            'as' => 'admin.', // This gets pre-pended to the route names.
            'middleware' => 'auth:admin',
            'namespace' => 'Admin'
        ],
        function () {
            Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard'); // with 'as' property, this becomes 'admin.dashboard'
            Route::resource('pages', 'PageController')->except(['show']);
        }
    );
```

Comment: No, this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting your admin and user domains in your `.env` file and then using `Route::domain` like so:

```
Route::domain(env('APP_ADMIN_URL'))->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
});

Route::domain(env('APP_USER_URL'))->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');
});
```

No need to touch your `htaccess` other than to make sure that your both of your domains route to your laravel public directory